# What would prevent filter from returning 0?

Tags: python, filter, boolean

When I try to filter `[1,2,0,3,8]` with `if x < 3: return x` I end up with `[1,2]`. Why is the `0` not included in this list?

```
def TestFilter(x):
    if x < 3: 
        return x

a = [1,2,0,3,8]
b = filter(TestFilter, a)
print b
```

Comment: I edited your question to use code formatting.

Comment: Do you know about lambda functions? Also, you should be returning `True` or `False` from your function — not just sometimes returning. (This issue probably occurs because 0 is falsey, even when returned.)

Comment: Hint: `0` is falsey in Python, so `return 0` is the same as `return False` in the context of a boolean value.

Comment: Very nice question.  Just as a reminder, don't forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem.  You can accept an answer by clicking on the little checkmark next the the answer.  It's good for the SO community (people can see quickly which answers work and people who answer don't waste time looking at already answered questions).

Comment: Also, note that `filter` is not very Pythonic. Guido himself encourages using a list comprehension or generator expression like so: `[x for x in a if x < 3]`. This also has better performance, since it avoids extra function calls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every time your function returns `True` [filter()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) will add the current element from the original list to the new list. Python considers `0` to be `False` and any other number to be `True`. Therefore you will want to have the function return `True` instead of the number.

```
def TestFilter(x):
    if x < 3: 
       return True
```

**EDIT:** Here's a lambda example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 8]
print filter(lambda x: x < 3, a)
```

Comment: @DSM I was really tempted to write a `lambda` instead... ;)

Answer (score 3):

When filtering you want to be returning True or False.  Here's what you want:

```
def TestFilter(x):
    return x < 3
```

When you filter using this, you'll get the results you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! My mistake for misunderstanding how it should be used.